# Simpson's rule is not producing better results than Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I have to calculate RMS value $\sqrt {\int_0^T\frac 1T*f(t)^2dt} $ and I know from the maths that the Simpson's rule should provide better approximation of the definite integral than the Riemann sums. Therefore I tried that out in Matlab, but here is what I got:

```
vin=115*sqrt(2)*sin(2*pi*400*(1:0.008:5));
rms(vin)%this is 114.8852
rms_calc_simpson(vin) % this is 114.7918
```

where the matlab function for the simpson's rule is:

```
function y = rms_calc_simpson(vout)
    [~,N]=size(vout);
    s=vout(1)^2;
    coef=4;
    for i=2:1:(N-2)
        s=s+coef*vout(i)^2;
        if coef==4
            coef=2;
        else 
            coef=4;
        end
    end
    if coef==4
        s=s+vout(N-1)^2;
        y=sqrt(s/3/(N-1));
    else
        s=s+4*vout(N-1)^2+vout(N)^2;
        y=sqrt(s/3/N);
end
```

So what could be the problem? I have double checked my simpsons function and it seems really ok. Could it be the case that Riemann Sums do produce better results than the Simpson's?

Comment: Could you please add to your question: 1. What RMS value (as an integral in mathematical notation) you're trying to compute; 2. Which Riemann sum(e.g., the midpoint sum) you're comparing against Simpson's rule; 3. Some code comments indicating what each subroutine in your Simpson's rule calculation does (for the benefit of possible respondents who don't speak Matlab). Thanks.

Comment: The Riemann Sum should be leftpoint sum. In the Simpson's rule code there are no subroutines called, apart from the matlab function sqrt which takes the root of the argument.

Comment: By "subroutines" I mean the loops and conditionals. :) Since it appears you're integrating a sine wave over one period, the left-hand sum will, in fact, be "better than expected". However, I can't completely understand what your code purports to do, including _what integral you are trying to calculate_ ($115\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1} \sin(800\pi x)\, dx$...?) and _how exactly you implement Simpson's rule_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a signal with a frequency of $f=800$, as $$\sin^2(2\pi· fx)=\frac12(1-\cos(2\pi·2fx)).$$ To get any useful result you need a sampling frequency of at least $1600$ resp. $$dx < 0.000625.$$

Your $dx=0.008$ is one magnitude too large.

---

Or to put it another way, the error term of an order $p$ method is dominated by $(f·dx)^p$ (with $f$ the essentially largest frequency), so you need at least $dx < 1/f=0.00125$ to get any useful result, usually you want $dx \ll 1/f$.